# Calcular valor en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este código con el cual necesito que de acuerdo al valor obtenido de la base de datos me cargue una imagen de un color específico.

Ejemplo: *>=11 img verde, >=4&<11 img naranjo, <4 img rojo.*

En los extremos no tengo problema, donde no me ha resultado es el cálculo entre 11 y 4 para el color naranjo.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
    if ((intval(($row_f1['prom']) >= '11'))) {
        echo "<img src='img/btn1.png'>";
        /*verde*/
    } elseif (intval(($$row_f1['prom'] >= '4')) && intval(($$row_f1['prom'])) <= '10.9') {
        echo "<img src='img/btn2.png'>";
        /*naranjo*/
    } else {
        echo "<img src='img/btn3.png'>";
        /*rojo*/
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola Juan será el doble signo de dólar ($$) en la variable

Comment: No conozco las normas de la comunidad en español, pero en SO original las preguntas no lleven llevar el título de etiquetas. Alguien lo aclare y edite la pregunta si es apropiado

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé aquí es válido, en todo caso puedes hacer un tour por las normas del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

El problema puede ser la manera en que estas poniendo `$$row_f1['prom']`, si te das cuenta estas poniendo un signo de precio de más.

Te aconsejo que para evitar estos problemas, asignes a una variable antes de abrir la condicional. Ejemplo:

```
$rowf1 = $row_f1['prom'];

if ($rowf1 >= 5){
 echo 'Es mayor o igual a 5';
} else {
 echo 'No es mayor o igual a 5';
}
```

Asi evitas tener que estar escribiendo algo largo y tedioso como `$row_f1['prom']` a cada rato, y le da más claridad y legibilidad a tu código :)

Comment: El asignar un elemento de una lista a otra variable no evitará errores de sintaxis. En todo caso hará el código más legible o más como de escribir, lo cual es discrepable.

Comment: Obviamente no lo hará. Sin embargo tendrá un código más limpio, legible y claro, y podría identificar más rápido sus errores de sintaxis, como este.

Answer (score 2):

Mis dos centavos aquí son para optimizar un poco el código exhibido, el error debería ser el explicado por Hoose (me basaré levemente en su respuesta) y A. Felipe Trujillo:

```
<?php

// almacenamos el valor a evaluar en otra variable
$valor = intval($row_f1['prom']);

// usamos el último valor posible como valor por defecto
// para obviar un condicional
$salida = 3;

if ($valor >= 11) {

    $salida = 1;

} elseif ($valor >= 4 && $valor < 11) {

    $salida = 2;

}

// agregamos el valor resultado a la parte de texto resultante que no cambia
echo "<img src='img/btn$salida.png'>";
```

Comment: Me gustaría que valoraran más esta respuesta porque esta más explicita y enriquecida que las demás (Incluyendo la mía).

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que la función `intval` toma la parte entera de un número no le veo sentido a que en tu código tengas `intval(($row_f1['prom'])) <= '10.9'` únicamente con colocar `intval(($row_f1['prom'])) < 11` es suficiente

Comment: Esto tanpoco es una repuesta a la pregunta. Es solamente un comentario. Por favor, añádelo como tal.